regex: how come the trademark symbol matches to a-z?
Sorry if this is a repeat or basic question but it is hard to search for a ™.  I'm writing a script to remove weird characters from file names.
How come the trade mark symbol ™ matches [^a-z] ???
$ echo "AMD Ryzen™ 5 2600X Processor rstuv" |sed 's/[^A-Z]//g'
AMDRXP

$ echo "AMD Ryzen™ 5 2600X Processor rstuv" |sed 's/[^a-z]//g'
yzen™rocessorrstuv

$ echo "AMD Ryzen™ 5 2600X Processor rstuv" |sed 's/[^s-t]//g'
ssst

$ echo "AMD Ryzen™ 5 2600X Processor rstuv" |sed 's/[^t-u]//g'
™tu

™ seems to be between t and u ?
Edit: System Specs:
$ locale
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ lsb_release -sdc; uname -sri
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
focal
Linux 5.4.0-172-generic x86_64

$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7



What is the output of locale? Some insight in this answer.

Here on Ubuntu 22.04 and en_GB.UTF-8 locale:
$ print -l {{s..u},{S..U}}{l..n} ™  | sort
sl
Sl
sm
Sm
sn
Sn
tl
Tl
tm
Tm

™
tn
Tn
ul
Ul
um
Um
un
Un

It definitely sorts between a and z, but then again T also sorts between a and z and these days, it's rare for [a-z] to match on T.
$ print -l {{s..u},{S..U}}{l..n} ™  | grep '^[a-z]'
sl
sm
sn
tl
tm
tn
ul
um
un
™

$ print -l {{s..u},{S..U}}{l..n} ™  | grep '^[A-Z]'
Sl
Sm
Sn
Tl
Tm
Tn
Ul
Um
Un


The fact that it's matched by [a-z] but not [A-Z] is more surprising. I don't know if it's intentional, but it may be explained by /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common (derived from https://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/14651/ed-4/ISO14651_2016_TABLE1_en.txt)  having <MNN><MNN> as the third weight (which is the one that carries case information for characters where that's relevant) instead of <CAP><CAP> which you'd need for that character to be considered as CAPital case, or the fact that it's not considered as uppercase [[ ™ = [[:upper:]] ]] (and [[ ™ = [[:lower:]] ]] for that matters) returns false.
<U2122> "<S0074><S006D>";"<BASE><BASE>";"<MNN><MNN>";<U2122> % TRADE MARK SIGN

I don't know what MNN stands for, but it seems to be used in all superscript characters, some of which uppercase letters, some of which lowercase letters.
In any case, if you want to match on abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, use [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz], not [a-z] which has no reason to include only those 26 letters except in contexts (such as in zsh globs or perl/PCRE/PCRE2 regexps) where the range is based on code point value (in most character sets that have those 26 letters, they are contiguous and in that order).
On that same Ubuntu 22.04 system, and same en_GB.UTF-8 locale, I find that the [a-z] range matches on:


 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzªºßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿāăąćĉċčďđēĕėęěĝğġģĥħĩīĭįıĳĵķĸĺļľŀłńņňŋōŏőœŕŗřśŝşšţťŧũūŭůűųŵŷſƀƃƈƌƒƕƙƚƛƞơƣƥƪƫƭưƴƾǆǉǌǎǐǒǔǖǘǚǜǝǟǡǣǥǧǩǫǭǰǳǵǹǻǽǿȁȃȅȇȉȋȍȏȑȓȕȗșțȝȟȡȣȧȩȫȭȯȱȳȴȵȶȷȸȹȼȿɇɉɋɍɏɐɑɒɓɔɕɖɗɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯɰɱɲɳɴɵɶɷɸɹɺɻɼɽɾɿʀʁʂʃʄʅʆʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏʙʚʛʜʝʞʟʠʣʤʥʦʧʨʩʪʫʮʯʰʱʲʳʴʵʶʷʸʻʽˠˡˢˣͣͤᴀᴁᴂᴃᴄᴅᴆᴇᴈᴉᴊᴋᴌᴍᴎᴏᴐᴑᴒᴓᴔᴕᴖᴗᴘᴙᴚᴛᴜᴝᴞᴟᴠᴡᴬᴭᴮᴯᴰᴱᴲᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴻᴼᴽᴾᴿᵀᵁᵂᵃᵄᵅᵆᵇᵈᵉᵊᵋᵌᵍᵎᵏᵐᵑᵒᵓᵔᵕᵖᵗᵘᵙᵚᵛᵢᵣᵤᵥᵫᵬᵭᵮᵯᵰᵱᵲᵳᵴᵵᵷᵹᵺᵻᵼᵽᵾᵿᶀᶁᶂᶃᶄᶅᶆᶇᶈᶉᶊᶋᶌᶍᶏᶐᶑᶒᶓᶔᶕᶖᶗᶘᶙᶛᶜᶝᶞᶟᶠᶡᶢᶣᶤᶥᶦᶧᶨᶩᶪᶫᶬᶭᶮᶯᶰᶱᶲᶳᶴᶵᶶᶷᶸᶹᶺ᷊ᷓḁḃḅḇḉḋḍḏḑḓḕḗḙḛḝḟḡḣḥḧḩḫḭḯḱḳḵḷḹḻḽḿṁṃṅṇṉṋṍṏṑṓṕṗṙṛṝṟṡṣṥṧṩṫṭṯṱṳṵṷṹṻṽṿẁẃẅẇẉẋẍẏẖẗẘẙẚẛẜẝẟạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽếềểễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừửữựỳỵỷỹỻỽỿⁱⁿₐₑₒₓₔₕₖₗₘₙₚₛₜ₨℀℁℃℅℆℉ℊℎℏℓ№℠℡™ℯℴℹ℻ⅆⅇⅈⅉ⅍ⅎⅰⅱⅲⅳⅴⅵⅶⅷⅸⅹⅺⅻⅼⅽⅾⅿↄ⒜⒝⒞⒟⒠⒡⒢⒣⒤⒥⒦⒧⒨⒩⒪⒫⒬⒭⒮⒯⒰⒱⒲⒳⒴ⓐⓑⓒⓓⓔⓕⓖⓗⓘⓙⓚⓛⓜⓝⓞⓟⓠⓡⓢⓣⓤⓥⓦⓧⓨⱡⱥⱦⱨⱪⱱⱳⱴⱶⱷⱸⱹⱺⱻⱼⱽ㉐㋌㋍㋎㋏㍱㍲㍳㍴㍵㍶㍷㍸㍹㍺㎀㎁㎃㎄㎅㎆㎇㎈㎉㎊㎋㎎㎏㎐㎑㎒㎓㎔㎖㎗㎘㎙㎚㎜㎝㎞㎟㎠㎡㎢㎣㎤㎥㎦㎧㎨㎩㎪㎫㎬㎭㎮㎯㎰㎱㎳㎴㎵㎷㎸㎹㎺㎻㎽㎾㎿㏀㏁㏂㏃㏄㏅㏆㏇㏈㏉㏊㏋㏌㏍㏏㏐㏑㏒㏓㏔㏕㏖㏗㏘㏙㏚㏛㏜㏝㏞㏟㏿ꜧꜩꜰꜱꜳꜵꜷꜹꜻꜽꜿꝁꝃꝅꝇꝉꝋꝍꝏꝑꝓꝕꝗꝙꝛꝝꝟꝡꝱꝲꝳꝴꝵꝶꝷꝺꝼꝿꞁꞃꞅꞇꞎꞑꞓꞔꞕꞗꞙꞛꞝꞟꞡꞣꞥꞧꞩꞵꞷꟷꟸꟹꟺꟻꟼꟽꟾꟿꬰꬱꬲꬳꬴꬵꬶꬷꬸꬹꬺꬻꬼꬽꬾꬿꭀꭁꭂꭃꭄꭅꭆꭇꭈꭉꭊꭋꭌꭍꭎꭏꭐꭑꭒꭓꭔꭕꭖꭗꭘꭙꭚꭜꭝꭞꭟꭢꭤﬀﬁﬂﬃﬄﬅﬆａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙ

characters in GNU grep but note that it also matches on collating elements made of more than one character, such as:
$ echo 'l\u00b7' | grep -x '[a-z]'
l·



abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸſƀƁƂƃƆƇƈƉƊƋƌƎƏƐƑƒƓƔƕƖƗƘƙƚƛƜƝƞƟƠơƢƣƤƥƦƩƪƫƬƭƮƯưƱƲƳƴƾǄǅǆǇǈǉǊǋǌǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǝǞǟǠǡǢǣǤǥǦǧǨǩǪǫǬǭǰǱǲǳǴǵǶǸǹǺǻǼǽǾǿȀȁȂȃȄȅȆȇȈȉȊȋȌȍȎȏȐȑȒȓȔȕȖȗȘșȚțȜȝȞȟȠȡȢȣȦȧȨȩȪȫȬȭȮȯȰȱȲȳȴȵȶȷȸȹȺȻȼȽȾȿɃɄɅɆɇɈɉɊɋɌɍɎɏɐɑɒɓɔɕɖɗɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯɰɱɲɳɴɵɶɷɸɹɺɻɼɽɾɿʀʁʂʃʄʅʆʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏʙʚʛʜʝʞʟʠʣʤʥʦʧʨʩʪʫʮʯʰʱʲʳʴʵʶʷʸʻʽˠˡˢˣͣͤᴀᴁᴂᴃᴄᴅᴆᴇᴈᴉᴊᴋᴌᴍᴎᴏᴐᴑᴒᴓᴔᴕᴖᴗᴘᴙᴚᴛᴜᴝᴞᴟᴠᴡᴬᴭᴮᴯᴰᴱᴲᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴻᴼᴽᴾᴿᵀᵁᵂᵃᵄᵅᵆᵇᵈᵉᵊᵋᵌᵍᵎᵏᵐᵑᵒᵓᵔᵕᵖᵗᵘᵙᵚᵛᵢᵣᵤᵥᵫᵬᵭᵮᵯᵰᵱᵲᵳᵴᵵᵷᵹᵺᵻᵼᵽᵾᵿᶀᶁᶂᶃᶄᶅᶆᶇᶈᶉᶊᶋᶌᶍᶏᶐᶑᶒᶓᶔᶕᶖᶗᶘᶙᶛᶜᶝᶞᶟᶠᶡᶢᶣᶤᶥᶦᶧᶨᶩᶪᶫᶬᶭᶮᶯᶰᶱᶲᶳᶴᶵᶶᶷᶸᶹᶺ᷊ᷓḀḁḂḃḄḅḆḇḈḉḊḋḌḍḎḏḐḑḒḓḔḕḖḗḘḙḚḛḜḝḞḟḠḡḢḣḤḥḦḧḨḩḪḫḬḭḮḯḰḱḲḳḴḵḶḷḸḹḺḻḼḽḾḿṀṁṂṃṄṅṆṇṈṉṊṋṌṍṎṏṐṑṒṓṔṕṖṗṘṙṚṛṜṝṞṟṠṡṢṣṤṥṦṧṨṩṪṫṬṭṮṯṰṱṲṳṴṵṶṷṸṹṺṻṼṽṾṿẀẁẂẃẄẅẆẇẈẉẊẋẌẍẎẏẖẗẘẙẚẛẜẝẞẟẠạẢảẤấẦầẨẩẪẫẬậẮắẰằẲẳẴẵẶặẸẹẺẻẼẽẾếỀềỂểỄễỆệỈỉỊịỌọỎỏỐốỒồỔổỖỗỘộỚớỜờỞởỠỡỢợỤụỦủỨứỪừỬửỮữỰựỲỳỴỵỶỷỸỹỺỻỼỽỾỿⁱⁿₐₑₒₓₔₕₖₗₘₙₚₛₜ₨℀℁ℂ℃℅℆ℇ℉ℊℋℌℍℎℏℐℑℒℓℕ№ℙℚℛℜℝ℠℡™KÅℬℭℯℰℱℲℳℴℹ℻ⅅⅆⅇⅈⅉ⅍ⅎⅠⅡⅢⅣⅤⅥⅦⅧⅨⅩⅪⅫⅬⅭⅮⅯⅰⅱⅲⅳⅴⅵⅶⅷⅸⅹⅺⅻⅼⅽⅾⅿↃↄ⒜⒝⒞⒟⒠⒡⒢⒣⒤⒥⒦⒧⒨⒩⒪⒫⒬⒭⒮⒯⒰⒱⒲⒳⒴ⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼⒽⒾⒿⓀⓁⓂⓃⓄⓅⓆⓇⓈⓉⓊⓋⓌⓍⓎⓐⓑⓒⓓⓔⓕⓖⓗⓘⓙⓚⓛⓜⓝⓞⓟⓠⓡⓢⓣⓤⓥⓦⓧⓨⱠⱡⱢⱣⱤⱥⱦⱧⱨⱩⱪⱭⱮⱯⱰⱱⱲⱳⱴⱵⱶⱷⱸⱹⱺⱻⱼⱽⱾ㉐㋌㋍㋎㋏㍱㍲㍳㍴㍵㍶㍷㍸㍹㍺㎀㎁㎃㎄㎅㎆㎇㎈㎉㎊㎋㎎㎏㎐㎑㎒㎓㎔㎖㎗㎘㎙㎚㎜㎝㎞㎟㎠㎡㎢㎣㎤㎥㎦㎧㎨㎩㎪㎫㎬㎭㎮㎯㎰㎱㎳㎴㎵㎷㎸㎹㎺㎻㎽㎾㎿㏀㏁㏂㏃㏄㏅㏆㏇㏈㏉㏊㏋㏌㏍㏎㏏㏐㏑㏒㏓㏔㏕㏖㏗㏘㏙㏚㏛㏜㏝㏞㏟㏿ꜦꜧꜨꜩꜰꜱꜲꜳꜴꜵꜶꜷꜸꜹꜺꜻꜼꜽꜾꜿꝀꝁꝂꝃꝄꝅꝆꝇꝈꝉꝊꝋꝌꝍꝎꝏꝐꝑꝒꝓꝔꝕꝖꝗꝘꝙꝚꝛꝜꝝꝞꝟꝠꝡꝱꝲꝳꝴꝵꝶꝷꝹꝺꝻꝼꝽꝾꝿꞀꞁꞂꞃꞄꞅꞆꞇꞍꞎꞐꞑꞒꞓꞔꞕꞖꞗꞘꞙꞚꞛꞜꞝꞞꞟꞠꞡꞢꞣꞤꞥꞦꞧꞨꞩꞪꞫꞬꞭꞮꞰꞱꞲꞳꞴꞵꞶꞷꟷꟸꟹꟺꟻꟼꟽꟾꟿꬰꬱꬲꬳꬴꬵꬶꬷꬸꬹꬺꬻꬼꬽꬾꬿꭀꭁꭂꭃꭄꭅꭆꭇꭈꭉꭊꭋꭌꭍꭎꭏꭐꭑꭒꭓꭔꭕꭖꭗꭘꭙꭚꭜꭝꭞꭟꭢꭤﬀﬁﬂﬃﬄﬅﬆＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙ

in the glob patterns of bash (the GNU shell) when the globasciirange option is on (as it is now by default). Note that it includes uppercase characters except the ASCII ones.


ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzªºÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸſƀƁƂƃƆƇƈƉƊƋƌƎƏƐƑƒƓƔƕƖƗƘƙƚƛƜƝƞƟƠơƢƣƤƥƦƩƪƫƬƭƮƯưƱƲƳƴƾǄǅǆǇǈǉǊǋǌǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǝǞǟǠǡǢǣǤǥǦǧǨǩǪǫǬǭǰǱǲǳǴǵǶǸǹǺǻǼǽǾǿȀȁȂȃȄȅȆȇȈȉȊȋȌȍȎȏȐȑȒȓȔȕȖȗȘșȚțȜȝȞȟȠȡȢȣȦȧȨȩȪȫȬȭȮȯȰȱȲȳȴȵȶȷȸȹȺȻȼȽȾȿɃɄɅɆɇɈɉɊɋɌɍɎɏɐɑɒɓɔɕɖɗɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯɰɱɲɳɴɵɶɷɸɹɺɻɼɽɾɿʀʁʂʃʄʅʆʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏʙʚʛʜʝʞʟʠʣʤʥʦʧʨʩʪʫʮʯʰʱʲʳʴʵʶʷʸʻʽˠˡˢˣͣͤᴀᴁᴂᴃᴄᴅᴆᴇᴈᴉᴊᴋᴌᴍᴎᴏᴐᴑᴒᴓᴔᴕᴖᴗᴘᴙᴚᴛᴜᴝᴞᴟᴠᴡᴬᴭᴮᴯᴰᴱᴲᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴻᴼᴽᴾᴿᵀᵁᵂᵃᵄᵅᵆᵇᵈᵉᵊᵋᵌᵍᵎᵏᵐᵑᵒᵓᵔᵕᵖᵗᵘᵙᵚᵛᵢᵣᵤᵥᵫᵬᵭᵮᵯᵰᵱᵲᵳᵴᵵᵷᵹᵺᵻᵼᵽᵾᵿᶀᶁᶂᶃᶄᶅᶆᶇᶈᶉᶊᶋᶌᶍᶏᶐᶑᶒᶓᶔᶕᶖᶗᶘᶙᶛᶜᶝᶞᶟᶠᶡᶢᶣᶤᶥᶦᶧᶨᶩᶪᶫᶬᶭᶮᶯᶰᶱᶲᶳᶴᶵᶶᶷᶸᶹᶺ᷊ᷓḀḁḂḃḄḅḆḇḈḉḊḋḌḍḎḏḐḑḒḓḔḕḖḗḘḙḚḛḜḝḞḟḠḡḢḣḤḥḦḧḨḩḪḫḬḭḮḯḰḱḲḳḴḵḶḷḸḹḺḻḼḽḾḿṀṁṂṃṄṅṆṇṈṉṊṋṌṍṎṏṐṑṒṓṔṕṖṗṘṙṚṛṜṝṞṟṠṡṢṣṤṥṦṧṨṩṪṫṬṭṮṯṰṱṲṳṴṵṶṷṸṹṺṻṼṽṾṿẀẁẂẃẄẅẆẇẈẉẊẋẌẍẎẏẖẗẘẙẚẛẜẝẞẟẠạẢảẤấẦầẨẩẪẫẬậẮắẰằẲẳẴẵẶặẸẹẺẻẼẽẾếỀềỂểỄễỆệỈỉỊịỌọỎỏỐốỒồỔổỖỗỘộỚớỜờỞởỠỡỢợỤụỦủỨứỪừỬửỮữỰựỲỳỴỵỶỷỸỹỺỻỼỽỾỿⁱⁿₐₑₒₓₔₕₖₗₘₙₚₛₜ₨℀℁ℂ℃℅℆ℇ℉ℊℋℌℍℎℏℐℑℒℓℕ№ℙℚℛℜℝ℠℡™KÅℬℭℯℰℱℲℳℴℹ℻ⅅⅆⅇⅈⅉ⅍ⅎⅠⅡⅢⅣⅤⅥⅦⅧⅨⅩⅪⅫⅬⅭⅮⅯⅰⅱⅲⅳⅴⅵⅶⅷⅸⅹⅺⅻⅼⅽⅾⅿↃↄ⒜⒝⒞⒟⒠⒡⒢⒣⒤⒥⒦⒧⒨⒩⒪⒫⒬⒭⒮⒯⒰⒱⒲⒳⒴ⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼⒽⒾⒿⓀⓁⓂⓃⓄⓅⓆⓇⓈⓉⓊⓋⓌⓍⓎⓐⓑⓒⓓⓔⓕⓖⓗⓘⓙⓚⓛⓜⓝⓞⓟⓠⓡⓢⓣⓤⓥⓦⓧⓨⱠⱡⱢⱣⱤⱥⱦⱧⱨⱩⱪⱭⱮⱯⱰⱱⱲⱳⱴⱵⱶⱷⱸⱹⱺⱻⱼⱽⱾ㉐㋌㋍㋎㋏㍱㍲㍳㍴㍵㍶㍷㍸㍹㍺㎀㎁㎃㎄㎅㎆㎇㎈㎉㎊㎋㎎㎏㎐㎑㎒㎓㎔㎖㎗㎘㎙㎚㎜㎝㎞㎟㎠㎡㎢㎣㎤㎥㎦㎧㎨㎩㎪㎫㎬㎭㎮㎯㎰㎱㎳㎴㎵㎷㎸㎹㎺㎻㎽㎾㎿㏀㏁㏂㏃㏄㏅㏆㏇㏈㏉㏊㏋㏌㏍㏎㏏㏐㏑㏒㏓㏔㏕㏖㏗㏘㏙㏚㏛㏜㏝㏞㏟㏿ꜦꜧꜨꜩꜰꜱꜲꜳꜴꜵꜶꜷꜸꜹꜺꜻꜼꜽꜾꜿꝀꝁꝂꝃꝄꝅꝆꝇꝈꝉꝊꝋꝌꝍꝎꝏꝐꝑꝒꝓꝔꝕꝖꝗꝘꝙꝚꝛꝜꝝꝞꝟꝠꝡꝱꝲꝳꝴꝵꝶꝷꝹꝺꝻꝼꝽꝾꝿꞀꞁꞂꞃꞄꞅꞆꞇꞍꞎꞐꞑꞒꞓꞔꞕꞖꞗꞘꞙꞚꞛꞜꞝꞞꞟꞠꞡꞢꞣꞤꞥꞦꞧꞨꞩꞪꞫꞬꞭꞮꞰꞱꞲꞳꞴꞵꞶꞷꟷꟸꟹꟺꟻꟼꟽꟾꟿꬰꬱꬲꬳꬴꬵꬶꬷꬸꬹꬺꬻꬼꬽꬾꬿꭀꭁꭂꭃꭄꭅꭆꭇꭈꭉꭊꭋꭌꭍꭎꭏꭐꭑꭒꭓꭔꭕꭖꭗꭘꭙꭚꭜꭝꭞꭟꭢꭤﬀﬁﬂﬃﬄﬅﬆＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙ

in bash globs with globasciirange off. Note how it also matches uppercase characters of ASCII (except Z).


abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzªºßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿāăąćĉċčďđēĕėęěĝğġģĥħĩīĭįıĳĵķĸĺļľŀłńņňŋōŏőœŕŗřśŝşšţťŧũūŭůűųŵŷſƀƃƈƌƒƕƙƚƛƞơƣƥƪƫƭưƴƾǆǉǌǎǐǒǔǖǘǚǜǝǟǡǣǥǧǩǫǭǰǳǵǹǻǽǿȁȃȅȇȉȋȍȏȑȓȕȗșțȝȟȡȣȧȩȫȭȯȱȳȴȵȶȷȸȹȼȿɇɉɋɍɏɐɑɒɓɔɕɖɗɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯɰɱɲɳɴɵɶɷɸɹɺɻɼɽɾɿʀʁʂʃʄʅʆʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏʙʚʛʜʝʞʟʠʣʤʥʦʧʨʩʪʫʮʯʰʱʲʳʴʵʶʷʸʻʽˠˡˢˣͣͤᴀᴁᴂᴃᴄᴅᴆᴇᴈᴉᴊᴋᴌᴍᴎᴏᴐᴑᴒᴓᴔᴕᴖᴗᴘᴙᴚᴛᴜᴝᴞᴟᴠᴡᴬᴭᴮᴯᴰᴱᴲᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴻᴼᴽᴾᴿᵀᵁᵂᵃᵄᵅᵆᵇᵈᵉᵊᵋᵌᵍᵎᵏᵐᵑᵒᵓᵔᵕᵖᵗᵘᵙᵚᵛᵢᵣᵤᵥᵫᵬᵭᵮᵯᵰᵱᵲᵳᵴᵵᵷᵹᵺᵻᵼᵽᵾᵿᶀᶁᶂᶃᶄᶅᶆᶇᶈᶉᶊᶋᶌᶍᶏᶐᶑᶒᶓᶔᶕᶖᶗᶘᶙᶛᶜᶝᶞᶟᶠᶡᶢᶣᶤᶥᶦᶧᶨᶩᶪᶫᶬᶭᶮᶯᶰᶱᶲᶳᶴᶵᶶᶷᶸᶹᶺ᷊ᷓḁḃḅḇḉḋḍḏḑḓḕḗḙḛḝḟḡḣḥḧḩḫḭḯḱḳḵḷḹḻḽḿṁṃṅṇṉṋṍṏṑṓṕṗṙṛṝṟṡṣṥṧṩṫṭṯṱṳṵṷṹṻṽṿẁẃẅẇẉẋẍẏẖẗẘẙẚẛẜẝẟạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽếềểễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừửữựỳỵỷỹỻỽỿⁱⁿₐₑₒₓₔₕₖₗₘₙₚₛₜ₨℀℁℃℅℆℉ℊℎℏℓ№℠℡™ℯℴℹ℻ⅆⅇⅈⅉ⅍ⅎⅰⅱⅲⅳⅴⅵⅶⅷⅸⅹⅺⅻⅼⅽⅾⅿↄ⒜⒝⒞⒟⒠⒡⒢⒣⒤⒥⒦⒧⒨⒩⒪⒫⒬⒭⒮⒯⒰⒱⒲⒳⒴ⓐⓑⓒⓓⓔⓕⓖⓗⓘⓙⓚⓛⓜⓝⓞⓟⓠⓡⓢⓣⓤⓥⓦⓧⓨⱡⱥⱦⱨⱪⱱⱳⱴⱶⱷⱸⱹⱺⱻⱼⱽ㉐㋌㋍㋎㋏㍱㍲㍳㍴㍵㍶㍷㍸㍹㍺㎀㎁㎃㎄㎅㎆㎇㎈㎉㎊㎋㎎㎏㎐㎑㎒㎓㎔㎖㎗㎘㎙㎚㎜㎝㎞㎟㎠㎡㎢㎣㎤㎥㎦㎧㎨㎩㎪㎫㎬㎭㎮㎯㎰㎱㎳㎴㎵㎷㎸㎹㎺㎻㎽㎾㎿㏀㏁㏂㏃㏄㏅㏆㏇㏈㏉㏊㏋㏌㏍㏏㏐㏑㏒㏓㏔㏕㏖㏗㏘㏙㏚㏛㏜㏝㏞㏟㏿ꜧꜩꜰꜱꜳꜵꜷꜹꜻꜽꜿꝁꝃꝅꝇꝉꝋꝍꝏꝑꝓꝕꝗꝙꝛꝝꝟꝡꝱꝲꝳꝴꝵꝶꝷꝺꝼꝿꞁꞃꞅꞇꞎꞑꞓꞔꞕꞗꞙꞛꞝꞟꞡꞣꞥꞧꞩꞵꞷꟷꟸꟹꟺꟻꟼꟽꟾꟿꬰꬱꬲꬳꬴꬵꬶꬷꬸꬹꬺꬻꬼꬽꬾꬿꭀꭁꭂꭃꭄꭅꭆꭇꭈꭉꭊꭋꭌꭍꭎꭏꭐꭑꭒꭓꭔꭕꭖꭗꭘꭙꭚꭜꭝꭞꭟꭢꭤﬀﬁﬂﬃﬄﬅﬆａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙ

for bash's [[ $c =~ ^[a-z]$ ]]. Same as grep and like in grep it also matches on multi-character collating elements.


abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

in zsh globs (based on codepoint). For [[ $c =~ '^[a-z]$' ]] it gives the same result as bash as it uses the same regexp library except when the rematchpcre option is enabled in which case it gives abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz as well as ranges are based on codepoint in PCRE.



What's print -l?

@aviro, print is a builtin shell command initially from ksh needed to address echo's mess. Found in ksh, zsh and bash though in bash that's only in a loadable builtin not always made available. The -l option to print the arguments one per line is zsh-specific though. POSIX ended up inventing a printf builtin instead of specifying ksh's print. So you could replace that print -l with printf '%s\n' (well actually, it's closer to printf '%b\n'.
